# Eclipse Mockito debugging; Doesn't stop on breakpoints in spied beans

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, mockito

I have a problem using Eclipse to debug Mockito based unittests. Tests are working fine but I cannot step in to spied code or stop on any breakpoint. Debugger is working fine in IntelliJ, but not in Eclipse.

I put a simple unittest to demonstrate my problem. I have JUnit test for SomeService which calls AnotherService. I'm using Mockito to mock output of AnotherService

**SomeService.java**

```
package com.example.my;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;
    public void callBoom() {
        System.out.print(anotherService.boom());
    }

}
```

**AnotherClass.java**

```
package com.example.my;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AnotherService {
    public String boom() {
        return "boom";
    }
}
```

**SomeServiceTest.java**

```
package com.example.my;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SomeServiceTest {
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    @Mock
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        doReturn("BOOM!!!").when(anotherService).boom();

    }

    @Test
    void testBoom() {
        someService.callBoom();
    }

}
```

I can see "BOOM!!!" printed, so mock is working. But if I put breakpoint into callBoom, Eclipse never stop on it. For other tests it doesn't stop at any method of "spied" beans. When you have larger unittest inability to debug it is very frustrating. I'm running Eclipse 2019-09 with JDK 1.8.0.221, but tried it on 2020-03 as well.

Comment: You mean you're putting the breakpoint on the line `System.out.print(anotherService.boom());` ?

Comment: @amseager Yes, I'm putting the breakpoint on `System.out.print(anotherService.boom())`, but Eclipse doesn't stop there (IntelliJ does)

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing a similar issue debugging with Mockito spied instances using VSCode